# get particular id at the top and other after

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching 50 ids from my database table. I want a particular id say 15 at the top and all the others after that. How can i do this using SQL query?

```
$sql = mysql_query("Select id from USERS");
```

I searched a lot but didn't find anything about this subject.I don't want to use two queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT id
FROM USERS
ORDER BY id != 15, id
```

`id != 15` will be `0` when `id` is 15, and `1` for all other values, so that row will be first. The remaining rows will be ordered by the `id`s.